# Add Value and remove value On button Click from Json Object

Tags: jquery, json

I want to added Value  to and remove from Json Variable using Button click can Any       body sugest?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help __("why isn't this code working?")__ must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce __it in the question itself.__ Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Question not really clear. No code example given. However, here is what i have understood from your description. 
Make sure your object is parsed properly first if its outputted through ajax.

```
//Removing from object
delete jsonobjectname[key or index]; 

//Adding to object
jsonobjectname[key or index] = yournewvalue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do provide sample code you tried or you have along with you. 
As per my understanding of your question if suppose following is the JavaScript object literal which can be taken from your JSON(JSON.parse method):

```
var data = {items: [
    {id: "1", name: "robot"},
    {id: "2", name: "harry"},
    {id: "3", name: "Apollo"}
]}
```

You don't need or want jQuery for this, just JavaScript.

**Adding an item:**

```
data.items.push(
    {id: "7", name: "Newton"}
);
```

That adds to the end. See below for adding in the middle.

**Removing an item:**

data.items.splice(1, 3); // Removes three items starting with the 2nd,
                         // (id: "2", name: "harry"

You can also add or remove value in middle using `splice` method.

After add/remove convert this object to JSON format and your job is done.